# Embedded Linux system not wrapping long lines

Tags: linux, terminal

I login to an embedded system running some favor of Linux using PuTTY. For some reasons, when displaying long line, the output is truncated on the right.

```
/proc/2872# echo $TERM
vt100
/proc/2872# stty
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint ixoff -imaxbel
/proc/2872# resize
COLUMNS=80;LINES=60;export COLUMNS LINES;

/proc/2872# cat cmdline
containerd--config/var/log/docker/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml--log-le
/proc/2872#
```

(the last output should have been longer, but truncated)

It seems that it knows I am using 80 columns but it just won't wrap the line. The same applies to cat, vi, etc. It is not that the tool truncated the line but rather the line wrap is not happening. How do I fix it?

Comment: The line truncation versus wrapping behavior is usually handled by the terminal emulation program that is displaying the text (on your host) rather than by the target (the *"embedded system"*).  You mention using Putty, but no other details.  If the console connection is a serial link, then I prefer to use minicom, and its `w` command toggles the *line wrapping* mode.  Putty should have a similar configuration option.

Comment: I'm using PuTTY to SSH. And SSH to other works fine. So I am confused why it behaves that way. But you just gave me an idea. `reset` fixes it!

Comment: FYI using SSH means you can't login in until a successful boot.  A serial console is a connection that is live from processor reset.

Comment: Could this be a problem of the prompt? See [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110102214648/http://drnathan.teamhackaday.com/2009/04/03/fix-your-linux-terminal-line-wrap-issues/).